# Shopify - Announcement Bar Update

Tags: html, css, shopify, liquid

I made a custom announcement bar for my website, and with it, it has a Free Shipping Counter. So, whenever a customer adds something to their cart, it shows them how much to add to get Free Shipping.

Only problem is, the text doesn't update unless the page is refreshed. I don't know how to go about this, but what I can see is that this is possible without a page refresh, as the number of items in the cart update immediately (right beside the cart icon).

Any help would be much appreciated. I will also link the code to the Announcement Bar when I have sorted this out (for those seeking an announcement bar with lots of customization options).

Comment: Here's my [Announcement Bar](https://github.com/DogFoxX/Announcement-Bar) code.

Comment: Anyone got any solutions to this issue? I've not made any progress, and can't find any solutions through Google.